# Anything helpful about Fortran stack overflow?

Tags: fortran, stack, stack-overflow, heap-memory, abaqus

In fact I am doing FEM analysis using ABAQUS with UMAT written in Fortran. The UMAT contained the I/O txt file to read several nearly 500x500 realx8 arrays, besides I have also stated several same size arrays in Fortran program. When I reduce the size of arrays to a small number like 10x10, the whole program work well without errors.
However when I want to deal with large arrays like 500*500, the abaqus shows like this

```
Error in job Job-1: The executable standard.exe aborted with system error code 1073741571.
```

I have searched many documents, which have told me that this error code means **stack overflow in Fortran**.
As far as I know, ABAQUS use win86_64.env/abaqus_v6.env to modify the Fortran compiler. The relevant code blocks like this,

```
compile_fortran=['ifort','/Qmkl:sequential',
                 '/c','/DABQ_WIN86_64', '/extend-source', '/fpp',
                 '/iface:cref', '/recursive', '/Qauto-scalar',
                 '/QxSSE3', '/QaxAVX',  
                 '/heap-arrays:1',
                 # '/Od', '/Ob0',  # <-- Optimization Debugging
                 # '/Zi',          # <-- Debugging
                 '/include:%I']
```

Some documents say that the 'heap-arrays' has something to do with stack/heap storage,

```
This option puts automatic arrays and arrays created for temporary computations on the heap instead of the stack.
If heap-arrays is specified and size is omitted, all automatic and temporary arrays are put on the heap. If 10 is specified for size, all automatic and temporary arrays larger than 10 KB are put on the heap.
```

I have tried to modify the **/heap-arrays:[size]** to different number, however, it always shows same error code.
Could anyone familiar with ABAQUS/Fortran give some advice? I will owe my gratitude.

PS. The Link option is something like this,

```
link_sl=['LINK',
         '/nologo', '/NOENTRY', '/INCREMENTAL:NO', '/subsystem:console', '/machine:AMD64',
         '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB', '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB',
         '/DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFCOREMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFPORTMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBMMD.LIB',
         '/DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib',
         '/FIXED:NO', '/dll','/STACK:100000000',
         #'/debug', # <-- Debugging
         '/def:%E', '/out:%U', '%F', '%A', '%L', '%B', 
         'oldnames.lib', 'user32.lib', 'ws2_32.lib', 'netapi32.lib', 'advapi32.lib']

link_exe=['LINK',
          '/nologo', '/INCREMENTAL:NO', '/subsystem:console', '/machine:AMD64', '/STACK:20000000',
          '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB', '/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:OLDNAMES.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFCOREMD.LIB',
          '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBIFPORTMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:LIBMMD.LIB', '/DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib',
          '/DEFAULTLIB:user32.lib', '/DEFAULTLIB:advapi32.lib',
          '/FIXED:NO', '/LARGEADDRESSAWARE','/STACK:100000000',
          # '/debug', # <-- Debugging
          '/out:%J', '%F', '%M', '%L', '%B', '%O',
          'oldnames.lib', 'user32.lib', 'ws2_32.lib', 'netapi32.lib', 'advapi32.lib']
```

Comment: Have you tried ulimit?

Comment: @Holmz, in fact I'm not familiar with compiling configuration, would you mind showing the detailed sentences?

Comment: Changing the value of /heap-arrays won't do anything useful - I recommend leaving the value off (or specifying zero if using the Visual Studio IDE.), but 1 is fine too. If the error is happening in MKL or ABAQUS, /heap-arrays won't help you.

"ulimit" is for Linux. On Windows, the stack size is set by the linker. You would need to modify linker options to expand the stack. (/stack:100000000 might help.) If this is indeed a stack issue.

Comment: @SteveLionel, Thanks for you advice. After several attempts, I have found the reason might be that the local arrays in UMAT have taken much storage, however, when I just compile nearly the same code in Visual Studio with IVF, it did not show errors. I do not know how ABAQUS manage the storage of UMAT, but the problem probably lies there.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but for others: I highly suggest making the local arrays `allocatable`.